# Beautifulsoup showing duplicates

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So basically I am new to Beautifulsoup and my final goal is to put some html in a field in a JSON dictionary were the Key would be the HTML tag and the value of the dict would be the HTML content.

Since I do not know what HTML I will be receiving I have to make this dynamic.

In my testing I got some duplicate output when I was trying to create this dictionary that I mentioned.

Basically I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if self.description:
    print "original: ", self.description

    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.description)
    print "changed: "

    for tag in soup.find_all(True): # find all tag
        print tag
```

The output:

```html
original:  
<p><strong>My name is james bond</strong></p>
<p><strong>​007</strong></p>

changed: 
<p><strong>My name is james bond</strong></p>
<strong>My name is james bond</strong>
<p><strong>​007</strong></p>
<strong>​007</strong>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over **all tags**. Since HTML is a nested tree structure, that means you will see tags multiple times; first as children of tags further up, then the tags themselves. `<strong>​007</strong>` is nested inside the `<p>` tag for example, so it shows up there first.

You'll have to loop over *one level of tags* instead if you don't want this:

```
for tag in soup.body or soup:  # prefer the body tag if exists
    print tag
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <p><strong>My name is james bond</strong></p>
... <p><strong>007</strong></p>
... ''')
>>> soup.body
<body><p><strong>My name is james bond</strong></p>
<p><strong>007</strong></p>
</body>
>>> for tag in soup.body or soup:  # prefer the body tag if exists
...     print tag
... 
<p><strong>My name is james bond</strong></p>


<p><strong>007</strong></p>
```

Comment: but i wanted my output to be `<p>` and then `strong` so i can fill up my dictionary with the key as the html tag and then the corresponding content in the value. How can i do that?

Comment: @psychok7: And what if the tag contains no other tags, just text? Or nothing. Or multiple tags? It all can be done, but you *didn't specify* any expected outcome.

Comment: i updated my question with the final dictionary example of what i am looking for

Comment: @psychok7: but you have *multiple `<p>` tags*. Keys in a dictionary must be unique. What do you intend to do with the other `<p>` tag?

Comment: you are right, i didn't think about that problem. do you have any advice?

Comment: @psychok7: I have no idea what actual problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: i am going to try another approach but i still mark your answer as the correct one as it solved the problem i was having. thanks